# [1, 3, 5]から[[1], [1, 3], [3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]を作るには？

Tags: ruby

[1, 3, 5]から[[1], [1, 3], [3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]を作るスマートな書き方はありませんか？

上記間違えてました。
[1, 3, 5]から[[1], [3], [5], [1, 3], [3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]です。
[1, 2, 3, 4]だと、[[1],[2],[3],[4],[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]です。

Comment: 規則をまちがえていました。訂正して例を増やしました。

Comment: いいかんじになりましたね，これなら説明はなくていいかも．

Answer (score 3, accepted):

こんな感じでできました。

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
a.each_cons(1).to_a  + a.each_cons(2).to_a + a.each_cons(3).to_a
```

配列のサイズによらないやり方はこんな感じでしょうか。

```
a = [1, 3, 5]
a.size.times.map{|i| a.each_cons(i+1).to_a}.flatten(1)
```

Comment: each_cons ！！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

tmtmsさんの回答を参考に、別解を考えてみました。

```
def hoge(arr, size = 1)
  (size <= arr.size) ? arr.each_cons(size).to_a + hoge(arr, size + 1) : []
end

hoge [1,3,5]  #=> [[1], [3], [5], [1, 3], [3, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Comment: 再帰してるんですね！テクいと思います。